# How to set @Required field in Spring without using the application-context.xml file?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I am using Spring-Boot and I am trying to set the required properties (i.e. properties with the @Required tag) of an implemented Service without using the application-context.xml file. In my application-context.xml file the service looks like this:

```
<bean class="services.impl.MyServiceImpl">
    <property name="property" value="value" />
</bean>
```

I guess that the properties looks something like this in Java:

```
protected Properties buildMyServiceImplProperties()
{
    Properties myServiceImplProperties = new Properties();    
    myServiceImplProperties.setProperty("property", "value");
    return myServiceImplProperties;
}
```

**EDIT:** The service class MyService is define as follows:

```
package services;

public interface MyService {}
```

And the implementation is:

```
package services.impl;

import services.DoctorService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    private String value;

    @Required
    public void setProperty(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, but if you're wanting to create that bean in Java Config, you only need something like this:

```
@Bean
public MyService(){
  MyService service = new MyServiceImpl();
  service.setProperty("property", "value");
  return service;
}
```

Comment: No, this does not work because the method setProperty is not part of the class. The property must be injected configuring the @Bean somehow.

Comment: @Gorayni can you update your post with MyServiceImpl?